# Проблемы с чтением\записью файла после экспорта из Eclipse

Tags: java, файлы, eclipse, запись

Всем привет!

Столкнулся с проблемой: при запуске кода из под Eclipse код работает нормально, но после экспорта в jar файл File.canRead() и сanWrite() выдает false, что приводит к неработоспособности программы, хотя файл существует (Создал в среде и нигде не удаляю).

Проблемный код инициализации файла:

```
static File data = new File("data/data.txt");

    data.setWritable(true, true);
    data.setReadable(true, true);

    if(!data.canRead() || !data.canWrite()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error file! Read: " + data.canRead() + " Write: " + data.canWrite() + " Patch: " + data.getAbsolutePath());
        return;
    }
```

Содержание Manifest.ML:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: ua.com.swgroup.homechat.homechat
Application-Name: HomeChat
Permissions: all-permissions
```

Порядок экспорта на 1 скрине.
Окно после запуска на 2 скрине.

PS: Также после экспорта создается масса левых классов, буду рад если объясните почему они создаются (В главном методе есть enumы с ClientID, ImageType, MessagePosition) - сделал скрин под номером 3.

**Все скрины:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/izoGa.jpg

Comment: Файл где лежит во время запуска в Eclipse? И где во время запуска как jar? Или он должен находится внутри jar?

Comment: Он находится внутри jar в папке data/data.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суть в том, что по строке он ищет папку и файл в ней РЯДОМ с jar.
Дабы получить доступ к файлам внутри jar, надо немного замарочиться:

```
new File(getClass().getResource("data/data.txt").getPatch());
```

При этом такую конструкцию **нельзя вызвать в статическом методе**!

Для абсолютного адреса нужно писать начиная с "/"

```
.getResource("/com/abc/package/resources/");
```

Comment: `data = new File(getClass().getResource("data/data.txt"));` - выкидывает The constructor File(URL) is underfined. Если прибавляю getPatch() - компилируется нормально, но проблема: getPatch() возвращает путь уже в пакете рядом с классом, или в корне jar? PS: метод не статичный.

Comment: О не статичности я предупреждал, а о абсолютном адресе добавил информацию в ответе.

Comment: Что то я туплю и туплю.... http://imgur.com/9d4OBNj - скинул иерархию

Comment: Лучше сделай папку в src

Comment: http://imgur.com/Jhghpic - cделал так, но при запуске (и через еслипс и через jar) опять старая ошибка что нельзя читать\записывать. Пробовал пройтись по '" Patch: " + data.getAbsolutePath()' - файл есть, после экспорта путь тоже корректно отображается.

Comment: Тоесть файл виден, но не дает считывать? Или тебе именно запись нужна?

Comment: Файл вроде виден. Мне нужно и чтение и запись. http://imgur.com/AYacRJB

Comment: Вот тут точно уже облом. JVM блокирует запущенный jar, поэтому самого себя не перезапишешь. Считывать еще ладно, а вот если записывать то надо вытащить наружу и положить рядом с jar. А там можно и старый способ использовать.

Comment: Эх... Ну ладно, спасибо за ответ. Хоть ресурсы научился делать :)